# Alternatives to pattern rules with .PHONY targets in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, bioinformatics

I am writing a pipeline in make to analyse biological data. There are three distinct sections of the pipeline, the first is to check the quality of the data, the second is to clean the data, and third is to align the data. After each section is complete I would like to manually inspect the results before I move on with the next. Therefore, instead of having a single chain of pattern rules, I want to be able to call each section using a phony target (similar to how you call clean). For example:

```
make analysis.pipeline quality
make analysis.pipeline trim
make analysis.pipeline align
```

Here is my current makefile:

```
# analysis pipeline

include analysis.pipeline.config

# align data
all: $(sorted_bam)

$(results)/%.sorted.bam: $(results)/%.bam
    samtools sort $^ $(basename $@)

$(results)/%.bam: $(results)/%.sam
    samtools view -bS $^ > $@

$(results)/%.sam: $(results)/%.adaprm.fastq
    bowtie2 -x $(genome) -U $^ -S $@


# clean data
.PHONY: trim
trim: $(qc_processed) $(trimmed_fastq)

$(results)/%.adaprm_fastqc.html: $(results)/%.adaprm.fastq
    fastqc -o $(@D) $^

$(results)/%.adaprm.fastq: $(data)/%.fastq
    cutadapt -a AACCGGTT $^ > $@


# check data
.PHONY: quality
quality: $(qc_raw)

$(results)/%_fastqc.html: $(data)/%.fastq
    mkdir -p $(@D) && fastqc -o $(@D) $^
```

The makefile is written to run in a src directory, which is separate to where the targets and dependencies are built, namely data and results directories. Is it possible to call each section of my pipeline the way I intend to, will there be any issue if I run it in parallel, and is this the right way to get around not being able to use implicit pattern rules in phony targets?

**Updated makefile**

```
# objects = A.fastq B.fastq

.PHONY: quality
quality: A_fastqc.html B_fastqc.html C_fastqc.html

.PHONY: trim
trim: A.trimmed_fastqc.html B.trimmed_fastqc.html

.PHONY: align
align: A.sorted.bam.bai B.sorted.bam.bai

# ALIGN DATA SECTION
%.sorted.bam.bai: %.sorted.bam
    samtools index $^

%.sorted.bam: %.bam
    samtools sort $^ $@

%.bam: %.sam
    samtools view -bS $^ > $@

%.sam: %.trimmed.fastq %.trimmed_fastqc.html
    bowtie2 -x $(genome) -U $< -S $@

# TRIM DATA SECTION
%.trimmed_fastqc.html: %.trimmed.fastq
    fastqc $^

%.trimmed.fastq: %.adaprm.fastq
    seqtk trimfq $^ > $@

%.adaprm.fastq: %.fastq %_fastqc.html
    cutadapt -a AACCGGTT $< > $@

# CHECK QUALITY SECTION
%_fastqc.html: %.fastq
    fastqc $^
```

Comment: I don't fully follow your makefile (some variable defintions appear to be missing) but `make analysis.pipeline quality` is telling make to run two targets. That doesn't sound like what you meant for that to mean. In any case I think the right idea here is to write the makefile so that it can be used normally (as in chaining from top-to-bottom) and then write `.PHONY` targets that depend on all the various files that come as output from each "stage" so that you can jump in to the "pipeline" at any desired stage.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, what you have described would suit perfectly. I have updated my post with the new makefile. I have done a dry run of the pipeline by: 1) running without naming a target --> causes only the first recipe to run 2) running whilst naming either quality, trim, or align as targets --> causes the recipes from each section to run, including previous sections. This seems to work so I think I have put your suggestion into practice correctly, from the looks of the updated makefile does that seem right?